# CSS - Vertically align image inside div

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<h1>4 Channel DVR - High Res 960H WD1, (500GB HDD)</h1>
<div class="col-50 product-wrapper left">

<img class="product-image" src="http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/4-channel-dvr.jpg" alt="4-channel-dvr" width="522" height="283" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-398" />

</div>

<div class="col-50-end left"

Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here Description goes here 

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-50 {
    width: 49%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.col-50-end {
    width: 49%;
}
.product-wrapper {
     /*empty*/
}
.product-image {
    /*empty*/
}
```

What I am wanting to do is vertically align the image in the middle of the col-50 div. The descriptions will all be different lengths so the height will change each time and so the alignment would have to be centered vertically according.

Is there a cross-browser way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the columns side by side and center the image, you can use `display: table-row` on a container and `display: table-cell` on each column. Then you can change the widths to `50%`and remove the `2%` margin. Then to center the image, use `vertical-align: middle` on the containing column. Also, add `width:100%; height:auto;` to the image to make it fit the column.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/2jfj99dw/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Ian - I've actually copied the code but can't get it to work as per your demo; http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/product/1-camera-residential-system-hi-res/ - the bottom product is a copy of your demo

Comment: Remove the `left` class from the columns. The float is breaking the `table-cell` properties. It shouldn't be needed anymore anyway.